# Exception when stopping container for a with Spring + Quartz + Tomcat web application

Tags: spring, tomcat6, quartz-scheduler

When stopping Tomcat, I am getting the following exception:

> ...appears to have started a thread named [`org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-10`] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

How can I prevent it? I already have the `destroy-method` set to `destroy` on the `SchedulerFactoryBean` bean.

Comment: You don't need to specify `destroy-method` on factory beans, they handle their own lifecycle. What happens if you remove that, does the error still occur?

Comment: I think it might be a PermGen issue (argh, classloader errors). See this thread: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?92836-Quartz-Thread-Leaks-in-Spring-Web-Application

Comment: Is there some locked code in your job? like synchronize, reentrant lock...

Comment: **amir75**: I read that, but it happens even when I start and stop the server immediately (no class reloading).
**Treydone**: No locked code. And this happens even if the jobs were not executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just to say...

We have exactely the same error with Grails (wich is Spring -based) & Quartz on a tomcat server... The thread that can't be stopped are from Quartz pool
We've never managed to correct that

Comment: Good to know, Grooveek. Any memory leaks because of that on your app?

Comment: Nope, it happens only when stopping tomcat. When the JVM dies, it does it smoothly and left no memory behind